# How to locate webelement having dynamic id in numerical format only?

Tags: webdriver

How to locate web element having dynamic id in numeric format only?

we have tried by using contains() method

//a[contains(@id,'*')]

also tried as
//a[@id=.]

Comment: Can you paste sample dynamic id?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
//a[matches(@id,'\d')]
```